# Android : Using <include> with Android Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, xml, navigation-drawer

I have one navigation drawer, I want it with another LinearLayout, so how can I do it? Can I use `include` or `merge`, or is there a way to define them in a single layout file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include your another layout file with some other layout with

```
@include tag
```

You have to just include your layout id with this tag. You can find the document here 
[Re-using Layouts with](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)

Comment: That's what I am trying to ask, Navigation Drawers are no ordinary layouts. The XML file is nothing except a navigation drawer, so, how can I use some other layout in it.

Comment: You can include the layoutId of your another linearlayout in in your layout where you have define the navigation drawer. Means make a separate file wich will have your new layout and include that file id in the layout where you have define your navigation drawer.